# Splunk query using time an event occurs in one index and using it as a starting point to filter events in another index

Tags: splunk

What's the most efficient way to perform the following search?

1. Event occurs on index A at X time
2. Take X time and use it as a start point in index B
3. Search all occurrences of a field within index B, with additional filters, 5 minutes after that initial event time that occurred from index A

Example using Windows logs: after every successful login via event ID 4624 (index="security") for a particular user on a host, search all Sysmon event ID 1 (index="sysmon") process creation events on that specific host that occurred in a 5 minute window after the login event. My vision is to examine user logins on a particular host and correlate subsequent process creation events over a short period of time.

I've been trying to play with join, stats min(_time), and eval starttimeu, but haven't had any success. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `map`?  The `map` command runs a search for each result of another search.  For example:

````
index=security sourcetype=wineventlog EventCode=4624
```Set the latest time for the map to event time + 5 minutes (300 seconds)```
| eval latest=_time+300
| map search="search index=sysmon host=$host$ earliest=$_time$ latest=$latest$"
````

Names within `$` are field names from the main search.

Comment: in half a decade, I've never seen a valid use for `map` ... you've finally provided one :)